# Batch does not go to else command

Tags: batch-file

I have written a batch which check a specific folder & specific files are present on given or not if everything is ok it generate log as everything ok and if everything is not ok then it generate log as pls check. It run the loop but does not run the else command. what may wrong i am doing here. Kindly guide.

following is my batch file

```
@Echo off
set /p GLC=Type Languages Code :
For %%a in (%GLC%) do (
if exist "d:\nilesh\%%a\*.doc" ( 
if exist "d:\nilesh\%%a\%%a.mdb" (
if exist "d:\nilesh\%%a\%%a.log" (
@echo "Now %%a is ok ">>%%a.txt
Pause
))) else (
@echo "Please check %%a ">>%%a.txt)
)
```

Comment: I can't remember `.bat` file syntax, but I think that logic would only enter the `else` if the first condition failed.

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, your ELSE only fires if the first IF fails. This is easily seen if you use indentation to highlight the logical structure:

**original code with indentation**

```
@Echo off
set /p GLC=Type Languages Code :
For %%a in (%GLC%) do (
  if exist "d:\nilesh\%%a\*.doc" ( 
    if exist "d:\nilesh\%%a\%%a.mdb" (
      if exist "d:\nilesh\%%a\%%a.log" (
        @echo "Now %%a is ok ">>%%a.txt
        Pause
      )
    )
  ) else (
    @echo "Please check %%a ">>%%a.txt
  )
)
```

You could add many ELSE statements as Magoo suggests, but I think it is simpler to use a temporary indicator variable.

Also, I don't see the purpose of the FOR loop. You can use %GLC% directly in all your statements.

**corrected code**

```
@echo off
setlocal
set /p "GLC=Type Languages Code: "
set "root=d:\nilesh\%GLC%"
set "ok="
if exist "%root%\*.doc" if exist "%root%\%GLC%.mdb" if exist "%root%\%GLC%.log" set ok=1
if defined ok (
  (echo Now %GLC% is ok)>>"%GLC%.txt"
  pause
) else (echo Please check %GLC%)>>"%GLC%.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. if else command will run only if 1st condition is true then where should i modify my code to check all the condition are true.

Comment: @user3396039 - The problem isn't detecting when all conditions are true - your original code does that properly. The problem is detecting when any of the conditions are false. There is no way to do that with a single ELSE unless you employ a temporary indicator variable as I have done in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@Echo off
set /p GLC=Type Languages Code :
For %%a in (%GLC%) do (
if exist "d:\nilesh\%%a\*.doc" if exist "d:\nilesh\%%a\%%a.mdb" if exist "d:\nilesh\%%a\%%a.log" (
echo "Now %%a is ok ">>%%a.txt
Pause
) else (
echo "Please check %%a ">>%%a.txt)
)
```

Note that once `@echo off` has been executed, further `commands` do not require the `@` - all it does is to turn off the echoing for that one command (and that's already off...)

Your original code would only execute the `ELSE` clause if the first condition was true - that is - if `*.doc` did not exist.

Here is a simplified version, looking at only two files to show you the missing `else`. Three files is simply more of the same.

```dos
For %%a in (%GLC%) do (
 if exist "d:\nilesh\%%a\*.doc" ( 
  if exist "d:\nilesh\%%a\%%a.mdb" (
   echo "Now %%a is ok 
  ) ELSE (ECHO .MDB is missing)
 ) else (
 echo .DOC is missing)
)
```

And see how indenting helps...

Comment: Thanks for reply. what i want to check is if all condition must be true then OK message should display else CHECK message should display

Comment: The first block of code is a solution that should work, finding (or failing to find) the *.doc within the directory and the `.mdb` and `.log` files and reporting if any are missing. The second block of code is merely explaining why your original code failed, using a simplified version.